# Decorator design pattern -- how to inherit from multiple interfaces

Tags: java, decorator

I'm currently developing a game like Google T-Rex (where you can play offline). Throughout my design, I put my best effort to follow the decorator design pattern
(Interface --> abstract class --> concrete decorator)

For example, an concrete decorator  class `Dinosaur` extends `MoveableFigureBaseDecorator` which is the base decorator class that also implements `MoveableFigure` (So the Dinosaur class is composed of a `MoveableFigure` object).

Now the concrete decorator `Cloud` (See below) should have the behaviours of both `StaticFigure` and `MoveableFigure`. But the problem is I'll have to implment methods in the interface `StaticFigure` even if they are already implemented in the Abstract decorator `StaticFigureBaseDecoator` (Which is not shown here, but follows the same pattern as in `MoveableFigureBaseDecoator`. Is there a way to overcome this code redundancy? Note the reason why `MoveableFigureBaseDecoator` and `StaticFigureBaseDecorator` aren't combined into one is because some classes should only have the behaviour of one but not the other.

Cheers.

```
interface StaticFigure extends Figure{
    
    //methodBToBeimplemented...
    
    
    
}
interface MoveableFigure extends Figure{
 
    //methodAToBeimplemented...
    
    
}

public abstract class MoveableFigureBaseDecorator implements StaticFigure {
    private MoveableFigure figure;
    
    MoveableFigureBaseDecorator(MoveableFigure f){
        //f is an instance of GameObject
        figure = f;
    }
    
    @Override
    void methodAToBeImplmented(){
        f.methodAToBeImplemented();
    }
    
    //Have to re-implement methods from StaticFigure!
}

public class Cloud extends MoveableFigureBaseDecorator implements StaticFigure{

    Cloud(MoveableFigure f){
        //f is an instance of GameObject
        super(f);
        //Some method calls of parent class
    }
 }

 public class GameObject implements MoveableFigure{

     void methodAToBeImplmented(){ //implementation for this method }

  }
```

Comment: "*the concrete decorator Cloud (See below) should have the behaviours of both StaticFigure and MoveableFigure*" - This doesn't seem right. How is it a static AND moveable figure? It sounds like `MoveableFigure` and `StaticFigure` share some common functionality. `MoveableFigure` should either derive from `StaticFigure` if that's your goal, or you'll need to define a new type composed of shared functionality, and inject them.

Comment: Yes I do want the behaviours from both...Maybe I named my class a bit inappropriately.

Comment: You are saying `MoveableFigure` should only have 1 of the two behaviors, which justifies why they aren't "combined". But you're also saying `MoveableFigure` should have both behaviors? Or is it just `Cloud` which should have both, and not all `MoveableFigure` instances will have static behavior? If it's the former, as in all moveable figures should also have static behavior, then `MoveableFigure` should inherit the behaviors of `StaticFigure` as well; they can't be 100% non-dependent on each other, unless `StaticFigure` has members that `MoveableFigure` should not have.